# apply a function to a matrix of lists in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, apply

I have a matrix of lists.

How do I apply a function to each set of the lists and return a matrix of the same dimensions as my original matrix?

I tried `apply(X=data.matrix , MARGIN=c(1,2) , function(x) min(x$P) )` but it returned `Error in min(x$P) : (converted from warning) no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf`

**EDIT**:
An example of the type of data I have:

```
data.matrix = list()

data.matrix$first = list()
data.matrix$second = list()
data.matrix$third = list()

data.matrix$first$a = data.frame(P=runif(3))
data.matrix$first$b = data.frame(P=runif(3))
data.matrix$first$c = data.frame(P=runif(3))

data.matrix$second$a = data.frame(P=runif(3))
data.matrix$second$b = data.frame(P=runif(3))
data.matrix$second$c = data.frame(P=runif(3))

data.matrix$third$a = data.frame(P=runif(3))
data.matrix$third$b = data.frame(P=runif(3))
data.matrix$third$c = data.frame(P=runif(3))

data.matrix = do.call(rbind,data.matrix)
```

I want to get the `min` (or whatever else) on each element of the matrix.

Thanks!

Comment: Reproducible example, please!

Comment: Example produced - thanks for the reminder :)

Comment: Try `sapply(data.matrix, function(x) min(x$P))`  If you need to fill the min values to replace the data.frame  `lapply(data.matrix, function(x) {x$P <- min(x$P);x})`

Comment: Technically, you have a two-dimensional list of data frames

Comment: Akrun, thanks, that worked! I was trying `apply` because it is a matrix and getting no where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
sapply(data.matrix, function(x) min(x$P))
```

If the `min` values should replace the `P` column

```
lapply(data.matrix, function(x) {x$P <- min(x$P);x})
```